# Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property customer invoice

Tags: jpa, entity, spring-data

I am new to spring based project,
 I have the requirement to create the entity relationship mapping between orders and invoices with OneToMany, and tried below mappings, but ending up with mapping error, 
Could you please point me out to fix this issue.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customers implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "CustomerId", nullable = false)
    private Long CustomerId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="Customers")
    private Set<Orders> Orders  = new HashSet<Orders>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
public class Orders implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "orderId", nullable = false)
    private Long orderId;

    @JoinColumn(name="CustomerId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Customers customers;

    @OneToOne (optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="orders",targetEntity=Invoices.class)
    private Invoices invoices;
    }

@Entity
@Table(name="Invoices")
public class Invoices implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "invoiceId", nullable = false)
    private Long invoiceId;

    @OneToOne(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,   mappedBy="invoices",targetEntity=Orders.class)
    private Orders orders;
}
```

Error message:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.mycompany.myproject.persist.entity.Orders.Customers in com.mycompany.myproject.persist.entity.Customers.Orders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably because Orders has a property 'customers' and not 'Customers' (as specified by the 'mappedBy' attribute).

You should tidy up your class names and fields as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "CustomerId", nullable = false)
    private Long customerId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
    private Set<Order> orders  = new HashSet<Order>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "orderId", nullable = false)
    private Long orderId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CustomerId")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")
    private Invoice invoice;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Invoices")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "invoiceId", nullable = false)
    private Long invoiceId;

    @OneToOne(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "InvoiceId")
    private Order order;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, It's appreciated. it works. and helped me a lot.